# Picamera Python Library Alternatives

Tags: python, raspicam, webcam, shared-libraries

I'm looking for something like picamera python library, for USB webcams.
Is there a python library that allows for image capture, and streaming for USB web-cameras?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you try a module called `opencv`

you may install it by running the following command:

```
install python-opencv bindings, numpy
```

here is some example code to help you get started:

```
import cv2
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
img=cam.read()

cv2.namedwindow("camera", cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.imshow("camera",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroywindow("camera")
```

You can read more about it [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found this amazing [motion](http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/use-a-raspberry-pi-to-remotely-watch-your-home-1314466) package for Raspberry Pi. You can also check out this [method](http://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/). It works well with good quality webcams. For official documentation and support, visit this [link](http://lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome).